# Alternative to union operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to select data from 3 tables.I'm using an INNER JOIN between first and second table to get another field from 2nd table. But if there is not match, I have to replace it with another 1st table field.I am using the query below but it takes too long to process.Is there another way to do it

```
SELECT tba.field, tba.field1, tba.field2 AS test FROM tablea tba
   WHERE tba.field NOT IN (SELECT ta.field FROM tablea ta INNER JOIN tableb tb ON ta.field = tb.field)
UNION
SELECT ta.field, ta.field1, tb.field2 AS test FROM tablea ta
     INNER JOIN tableb tb ON ta.field = tb.field
UNION
SELECT tc.field, tc.field1, tc.field2 AS test FROM tablec tc
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67ec14/4/0)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - and note that questions about query performance ALWAYS require, at a minimum, SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables AND the results of the EXPLAIN.

Comment: are you using sub query at not in and second query for union is same. why ?

Comment: @strawberry I added the link.

Comment: @Krishn, I have the get data that doesn't match the inner join on second query

Comment: @khalil than you can use left join let me ans it

Comment: @khalil have you checked my answer?

Comment: @stephen, I tested.It's much more elegant but I want to know If I can do a query without UNION operator. It takes much time on bigger data

Comment: @khalil how does `tablec` relate to the other tables? if there's no relation then you can not avoid `union`

Comment: @stephen, tablec has the same columns (with additionnal columns) with tablea

Comment: @khalil please check out my solution below.

Comment: @Suraz, you are using UNION ALL and subquery. Is it faster than Stephen one (LEFT OUTER JOIN) ?

Comment: @Stephen, thanks. I've tested on big data, it's much faster than the old query I was using

Comment: @khalil yes, you can check it with once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should suffice:

```
SELECT tba.field, tba.field1, COALESCE(tb.field2, tba.field2) AS test 
FROM tablea tba
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb tb ON  tba.field = tb.field
UNION
SELECT tc.field, tc.field1, tc.field2 AS test FROM tablec tc
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**: here is the alternative for query one and you can also use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` if data is not duplicate. `UNION ALL` is comparatively faster

```
SELECT ta.field1, ta.field2, IFNULL(tb.field2, ta.field3) AS mytest 
FROM tablea ta 
LEFT JOIN tableb tb ON ta.field3 = tb.field1
UNION ALL
SELECT tc.field1, tc.field2, tc.field3 AS mytest FROM tablec tc
```